# error in counting white pixels in image,matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a proplem when dealing with images in matlab, i have a white image and when i try to print the gray level of the image and increment it by 1 , it gives me 255, it never give me 256.
and here is the code. and the count is 0.

```
  function [ count ] = white( I )
    [row,col]=size(I);
    count=0;
    for x=1:row
        for y=1:col
            g=I(x,y);   %the value of the gray level on each pixel
            if((g+1) == 256)
            count=count+1;
            256
        end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What format (data type) is `I`? I assume it is 8-bit?

Answer (score 4):

Your image class is probably uint8 and 255 is the maximal value of this class . For example:

```
 >>  uint8(inf)

ans =

  255
```

Instead try to cast to a different class, for example `I=uint32(I)` ...

Following @Aganders3, I'll also offer a solution to your code that doesn't use for loops:

```
count=sum(I(:)>threshold); % Credit to @Jonas and @Aganders3
```

where threshold is the gray level you want to threshold

Comment: Instead of using `find`, I suggest you use `nnz(I>threshold)` or the probably faster `sum(I(:)>threshold)`.

Comment: Using a threshold is a better method, as it is much more flexible. I also agree with @Jonas that the call to `find` is unnecessary as it also provides the indices of the points (which he doesn't seem to need).

Comment: @Joans is absolutely right. (sum seem to be faster than nnz in this case after a quick check)

Comment: I is array for image, I dont want to modify the values of I, i want to store I(x,y) in g and increment g by 1; so the problem is g;does matlab treat g by default as unit8?

Comment: thanks all,
I just write 
    g=double(I(x,y));
and this solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think nate is correct on why this is not working.

Also, consider a much simpler solution to your problem (given `I` is full of integers):

`count = sum(vector(I == intmax(class(I))));`